# Docker login from cmd line yields i/o timeouts

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to login to docker from the Docker Quickstart Terminal but it doesn't work. 
I always get an error saying: "Error response from daemon: Server Error: Post https://index.docker.io/v1/users/: dial tcp: i/o timeout"

I have been working with docker the last few days and was always able to login and push/pull stuff. The only thing different I can think of is that I'm currently on a different Wifi.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Karsten

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, and is probably related to VirtualBox; after switching networks, boot2docker/VirtualBox sometimes looses connectivity or uses incorrect DNS settings.

- [DNS confused when switching WiFi networks](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/776)
- [Container connectivity lost after switching wireless networks](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/845)
- [Manual restart required everytime network connectivity changes](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/945) (contains some workarounds)

Docker Machine 0.5.3 adds two new options that may circumvent this;

- [`--virtualbox-dns-proxy`](https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/2467)
- [`--virtualbox-host-dns-resolver`](https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/2448)

Answer (score 1):

After restarting the machine it worked again, don't know what caused the problem though...